# Prevent Rails3 model from being created directly (only want to allow creation from within another model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I'd like to make sure that

```
MyModel.new # ...raises an error...
```

and that

```
MyOtherModel::create_my_model # ...only this should work!
```

What's a good way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing direct AFAIK. The following should work though.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  belongs_to :my_other_model
  def initialize( need_this_argument = nil )
    raise if need_this_argument.nil?
    super() # It is important to put the () here.
  end
end

class MyOtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_one :my_model
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :my_model
  def create_my_model(arguments)
    MyModel.new( true ) # Pass a non nil argument
  end
end
```

MyModel.new #=> RuntimeError 
a =MyOtherModel.new 
b = a.create_my_model 
..# Do your stuff here 
b.save 
a.save